# Is there a Jquery plugin for working with window resizing? (esp frames)

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

Is there a JQuery plugin that makes easier handling window resize events?

Specifically I would like the google maps iframe to resize when the window does - just like a div.

Can jquery help?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a plugin?.. check out [this article](http://www.wolfcreekconsulting.com/support/techlib/web/DynamicallyResizedIframes.php).

*Note: The article says they haven't tested it in IE6, and I don't have IE6 to check it out... but it works with IE8.